# Zabbix LLD Value should be a JSON object

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

Alright! Following is the scenario with respective queries:

1) I am using a bash script to generate JSON object for status of custom processes.

2) Providing the bash inside zabbix_agentd.conf file:

```
UserParameter=service.check[*],/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/service_check.bash
```

I want to provide the process names as parameters to the bash file here in UserParameter, how do I do that?

3) Restarting the zabbix-agent and checking with `zabbix-get` yields an empty JSON (because we have not given any process names):

```
{
    "data":[


    ]
}
```

4) If I provide a process name into UserParameter as:

```
UserParameter=service.check[*],/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/service_check.bash apache2 ntp cron
```

It yields the following:

```
{
     "data":[
```

which I know is wrong, since I need to pass the process names in a different way. I tried passing them inside the bash script and even then it generates an invalid json as above.

5) The JSON generated will be taken care by the Zabbix discovery rule of type "Zabbix agent", where it will create different items out of process names. Following is the JSON that my script should send:

```
{"data":[{"{#NAME}":"apache2","{#STATUS}":"RUNNING","{#VALUE}":"1"},{"{#NAME}":"ntp","{#STATUS}":"RUNNING","{#VALUE}":"1"},{"{#NAME}":"cron","{#STATUS}":"STOPPED","{#VALUE}":"0"}]}
```

I could have used `zabbix-sender` for the same, but it would need me to run the sender for every key-value that I need to send. Also, this way I have to be concerned with manipulating data at one place only, and the rest will be taken care of.

Hope this is clear enough and explains my situation.

Comment: The fault is in your script, /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/service_check.bash . How are you trying to read the parameters in there?

Comment: I am giving the parameters inside my script, such that upon execution it generates a json as follows:

```{"data":[{"{#NAME}":"ntp","{#STATUS}":"RUNNING","{#VALUE}":"1"},{"{#NAME}":"mysql","{#STATUS}":"RUNNING","{#VALUE}":"1"},{"{#NAME}":"prometheus","{#STATUS}":"STOPPED","{#VALUE}":"0"},{"{#NAME}":"apache2","{#STATUS}":"RUNNING","{#VALUE}":"1"}]}```

Comment: You said that it does not work, and that a truncated JSON is produced instead.

Comment: Let me explain again. When I do this:

```UserParameter=service.check[*],/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/service_check.bash```

The output is this empty json:

```{
    "data":[


    ]
}```

But when I add a parameter as this:
```UserParameter=service.check[*],/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/service_check.bash apache2 ntp cron```
It gives an invalid json as this:
```{
     "data":[```

Comment: Anyways, I got a workaround the situation for the time being. See, I redirected all the output from my bash script to a json file and then I cat the json file into UserParameter. This way too, the only thing I will have to alter is the array of process names in my bash script. But still I want to know a more modular solution to this. Your opinion will be much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to debug your script. Running it as `bash -x script.sh` might help. Note that Zabbix will run it as a different user and in a somewhat different environment.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Upon using -x option, I found the flaw in my script. Actually I was using shebang with -e option, so the script was failing at every service that had stopped. Sorry for the false alarm.